# Format a chart of random numbers from a .txt

Tags: java

I want to put a newline character at a certain position instead of all of my numbers then newline character.
I tried to put the newline character with `System.out.print("\n");` outside of the loop but I can't figure out how to put it at a certain position. I want my chart to be a simple 10 x 10 chart, with 10 numbers per row, 10 rows in total. My numbers.txt has 100 random numbers.

```
import java.io.*;

public class numbersChart {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File myFile = new File("numbers.txt");
        Scanner text = new Scanner(myFile);
        while (text.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.print("\n");
            System.out.printf("%6s", " ");
            System.out.print(text.nextInt());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how's the `numbers.txt` file look like?

Comment: 21  All numbers are vertical (one number per line)
14
9
38
90
46
54
47
60
34
2
5
25
33  
35
23
43

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need the while loop, the idea is to put `\n` after 10ths numbers.

Try the code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File myFile = new File("numbers.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(myFile);
    int d = 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < d * d; i++) {
        if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.print(scanner.nextInt());
        } else {
            break;
        }

        if ((i + 1) % d == 0) {
            System.out.println();
        } else {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Build your rows as you read the file pretty much in the same fashion as you are doing. Print each row (of whatever) as they are developed. Using a `while` loop to read the file is the usual practice for this sort of thing since you may not necessarily know exactly how many numbers may actually be contained within the file to generate the chart (table). In your particular case you for whatever reason know there are going to be 100 numbers. This however may not always be the case in other real world situations. Your code should be able to create table rows of ten (or whatever you desire) whether there is 1 number or 1 million (or even more) numbers in the file.

A slightly different play on the task would be to consider a numerical data file which contains any number of numerical values be it signed or unsigned integer, floating point or both. We want to read this file so to create and display a numerical table consisting of whatever desired number of rows with all rows consisting of whatever number of columns with the exception of perhaps the last row which there may not be enough values in the data file to accommodate the require number of columns. The columns are to also be spaced to our desired width when creating the table.

With the supplied code below, this can all be accomplished. Maximum Rows, columns, and table spacing is all configurable. I suggest you read the comments in code for further insight:

```
/* Create a numbers.txt file for testing. Save a copy 
   of your existing one somewhere else for safekeeping
   if you use this portion of code!                */ 
int quantityOfNumbers = 100;
// 'Try With Resources' used here to auto-close the writer.
try (java.io.PrintWriter writer = new java.io.PrintWriter(new java.io.File("numbers.txt"))) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= quantityOfNumbers; i++) {
        writer.append(String.valueOf(i)); 
        if (i < quantityOfNumbers) {
            writer.write(System.lineSeparator());
        }
    }
    writer.flush();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    System.exit(0);
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    
String fileName = "numbers.txt"; // The numerical data file to read.
int desiredColumns = 10;         // The number of columns per row you want.
int formatSpacing = 8;           // Each column will be this many spaces wide.
int maxRows = 0;                 // Max rows we might want. If 0 then unlimited.
    
java.io.File myFile = new java.io.File(fileName);  // File Object
    
// Read & process the numerical data file...
// 'Try With Resources' used here to auto-close the reader.
try (Scanner reader = new Scanner(myFile)) {
    String num;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");  // Used for building each numerical row
    int columnCounter = 0;                     // Used to keep track of columns added to 'sb'.
    int rowCounter = 0;                        // Used to keep track of the number of rows created.
    while (reader.hasNextLine()) {             // Read file until there is nothing left to read.
        num = reader.nextLine().trim();        // Retrieve data line on each iteration.
        /* Make sure the line in the file is actually a number
           and not something alphanumeric or a blank line. Carry
           out some form of validation. The regular expression
           (regex) within the matches() method allows for signed 
           or unsigned integer or floating point string numerical
           values. If it's invalid we skip the line. Remove this 
           `if` block if you want everything regardless:       */
        if (!num.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
            continue;
        }
        columnCounter++;  // Valid line so increment Column Counter by 1
        /* Format the string value as we append to sb. If you want the
           table values right justified then remove the '-' from the format.   */ 
        sb.append(String.format("%-" + String.valueOf(formatSpacing) + "s", num)); 
        if (columnCounter == desiredColumns) { // Have we reached our desired number of columns?
            System.out.println(sb.toString()); // Print the row to console.
            sb.setLength(0);                   // Clear the StringBuilder object (sb).
            columnCounter = 0;                 // Reset the Column Counter to 0. 
            rowCounter++;                      // Increment Row Counter by 1
            if (rowCounter == maxRows) {       // If we've reach our max rows then stop reading.
                break;                         // Break out of 'while' loop.
            }
        }
    }
    /* Reading has finished but is there anything that didn't
       make 10 columns worth of data? If the StringBuilder 
       object (sb) contains anything at this point then yes 
       there is something so print it to console window.    */
    if (!sb.toString().isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    // Whoops...can't find the numerical data file.
    System.err.println("Can not locate the numerical data file!"); 
    System.err.println("Data File: --> " + myFile.getAbsolutePath());
}
```